# Определить количество слов длиной 3 символа

Tags: c++

Дана строка текста, в которой слова разделены пробелами и запятыми. Необходимо:
Определить количество слов длиной 3 символа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int countWords(string st)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<st.size(); i++)  {
        if (st[i] == ' ')
            count++;  }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    string st = "\n So she was considering in her own mind, as well as she could, for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid,  whether  the  pleasure  of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and  picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran close by her.";
    cout<<st;
    cout<<"\n\n The string has "<<countWords(st)<<" words of tres characters.";
    _getch();
}
```

Я просто знаю, как найти количество слов, вы можете помочь мне пожалуйста.

Comment: Если после запятой не окажется пробела, то и количество слов вы неправильно посчитаете.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Такие задачи надо разбивать на части.

Сначала напишите функцию, которая просто перебирает слова и находит их длину

```
int next_word_length(const char*& str) {
  // пропускаем пробелы и пунктуацию
  while (*str != '\0' && !std::isalpha(*str)) ++str;

  // проверяем что строка не закончилась
  if (*str == '\0') return 0;

  int len = 0; // вычисляем длину слова
  while (std::isalpha(*str)) {
      ++len;
      ++str;
  }
  return len;
}
```

Потом напишите код который с помощью этой функции выводит слова с длиной равной 3

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int next_word_length(const char*& str);

int main() {
  const char* str = "\n So she was considering in her own mind, as well as she could, for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid,  whether  the  pleasure  of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and  picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran close by her.";

  int word_count = 0;
  while (int len = next_word_length(str)) {
    if (len == 3) {
      ++word_count;
      std::cout << std::string(str - len, str) << '\n'; // для отладки
    }
  }
  std::cout << "Words with len==3 : " << word_count << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Правильно было бы учитывать знаки пунктуации, а не только пробел или запятую, так как ваше предложение помимо этих знаков также содержит точку, и как раз последнее слово длиной 3 символа заканчивается точкой.

```
...by her.";
      ^^^
```

Функция может выглядеть следующим образом, как показано в демонстрационной программе ниже (я добавил к разделителям знак точки, хотя, как я уже написал, лучше было бы использовать любой знак пунктуации в качестве разделителя)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const std::string::size_type TARGET_LENGTH = 3;

std::string::size_type 
countWords( const std::string &s, std::string::size_type length = TARGET_LENGTH )
{
    const char *delimiter = " ,.";

    std::string::size_type count = 0;

    std::string::size_type pos = 0;
    while ( ( pos = s.find_first_not_of( delimiter, pos ) ) != std::string::npos )
    {
        std::string::size_type n = s.find_first_of( delimiter, pos );
        if ( n == std::string::npos ) n = s.size();

        count += n - pos == length;

        pos = n;
    }

    return count;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "\n So she was considering in her own mind, as well as she could, for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid,  whether  the  pleasure  of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and  picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran close by her.";

    std::cout << '[' << s << ']' << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"\n\n The string has " 
              << countWords( s ) << " words of " 
              << TARGET_LENGTH << " characters."
              << std::endl;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
[
 So she was considering in her own mind, as well as she could, for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid,  whether  the  pleasure  of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and  picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran close by her.]


 The string has 17 words of 3 characters.
```

Answer (score 1):

предлагаю следующую реализацию функции `countWords`

```
int countWords(string st)
{
    int count = 0;
    int currentLengthWord = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< st.size(); i++)
    {
        // проверяем, не конец ли это слова(здесь мы перечисляем любые символы, которые являются разделителем слова)
        if (st[i] != ' ' && st[i] != '!' && st[i] != '.' && st[i] != ',' && st[i] != '?' && st[i] != ':')
        {
            currentLengthWord++;
        }
        else
        {
            // конец слова, проверяем ее длину(равна ли 3)
            if(currentLengthWord == 3)
            {
                // длина слова равна 3, инкрементируем счетчик                количества слов
                ++count;
            }
            currentLengthWord = 0;
        }
    }
    // проверяем конец текста, если последнее слово также равно 3, то также инкрементируем
    if(currentLengthWord == 3)
        ++count;

    return count;
}
```

Comment: господин, который минусовал, оставьте пожалуйста ваш поясняющий комментарий, код вполне рабочий по-моему, что в нем не так?

Comment: эх, Вы, в отличии от меня, предусмотрели окончание строки:) +1

Answer (score 1):

Вот, вполне, рабочий вариант

```
    int position = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<st.size(); i++) {
       if(st[i]!=',' && st[i]!=' ') ++position;
       else {
           if(position == 3) ++count;
           position = 0;
       }
     }
    if(position == 3) ++count;
```

Comment: проверьте, если мы пошлем текст, в котором встречается, например, слово из 6 букв, то ваш алгоритм найдет два слова из 3 букв, хотя на самом деле, в этом случае, нет ни одного слова из 3 букв

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov вновь Вы правы, спасибо за правку:)

Answer (score 1):

Да, тут часто возникают вопросы (скорее всего учебные) в которых требуется вытаскивать слова (или числа) отделяемые друг от друга различными разделителями из файла (или строки)  и дальше что-то делать с ними (в Вашем случае определять длину и подсчитывать количество слов с длиной 3).

Вот очень простая маленькая функция, которая выбирает очередное слово из строки и позволяет упростить решение массы подобных задачек.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
 before call: *p -- ptr to start search WORD in delimiters
 after call:  *p -- ptr to next char after word (and *p - word == WORD length)
 returns ptr to WORD or 0
 */
char *
strtos (char **p, const char *delim)
{
  char *word = 0;

  if (*((*p) += strspn(*p, delim))) {
    word = *p;
    (*p) += strcspn(*p, delim);
  }

  return word;
}
```

Для понимания как она работает достаточно прочесть [man strspn](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strspn).

А вот как ее можно использовать  (Linux, файл c1.c)
(Извиняюсь, немного перепутал (невнимательно прочел вопрос), в Вашем случае нужен лишь внутренний цикл, после чего печатаете счетчик и сбрасываете его, а внешний можете считать тестовой обвязкой)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" { // предполагаем, что strtos оттранслирована gcc -c strtos.c
#endif
  // по хорошему все это д.б. в каком-нибудь подключаемом strtos.h файле
  char *strtos (char **start_lookup, const char *delimiters_str);
#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif

#define SEP " ,\n" // допустим, что слово все же не может переходить со строки на строку    
//#define SEP " \t\n\"\'.,;:+-*/(){}[]=?!~%^&\\" // а это для Си текстов (наверняка что-то упустил)

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  size_t lsize, wlen, n3 = 0;
  char *curline = 0, *start, *word;

  while ((getline(&curline, &lsize, stdin) > 0) && (start = curline)) 
    while (word = strtos(&start, SEP))
      n3 += (start - word == 3);

  return printf("%ld 3-length words\n", (long)n3) < 0;
}
```

Т.е. читаем файл построчно, вытаскиваем поочередно слова (разделяемые одним или более разделителями (пробел, запятая)) из прочитанной строки и если длина слова равна трем, увеличиваем счетчик.

Транслируем и запускаем

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ g++ c1.c strtos.o ; ./a.out <c1.c
7 3-length words
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте в комментариях (упоминая @avp, без собаки нотификация мне не поступит).